# Astronauts' sleeping heart rate on the ISS

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, sleep, health

On Earth during non-REM sleep a person's [heart rate goes down](https://www.livestrong.com/article/105256-normal-heart-rate-sleeping/).  Does the same thing happen on the ISS, or does the non-REM sleeping heart rate remain close to the heart rate of the astronaut while awake but not active?

Comment: Not on ISS, but during Apollo 11's team coast to the moon, bio data from sensors was used to check whether a person sleeping or not: (from Apollo Flight Journal): "Our Flight Surgeon reported a short while ago that Command Module Pilot Mike Collins appeared to be sleeping soundly at this time. Biomedical data on the other two crewmen indicates that they are still awake." I'm guessing here, but most likely the parameter to estimate sleeping or not was the heart rate.

Comment: @LeoS Is there any way I could research which measurements of the biomedical data were relevant?